# How to cut strings from special point

Tags: python, string

I have some car names like:

```
Mercedes-Benz C-Class C180 CGI,
BMW 3 Series 318i (New 5-yr COE),
Kia Cerato Forte 1.6M EX (COE till 03/2024) ...
```

I want to have out put like this:

```
Mercedes-Benz C-Class, 
BMW 3, 
Kia Cerato ...
```

I mean just two first parts. I tried below code and it works, but I want to know what is the better way and my problems:

```
In [21]: car = 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class C180 CGI'
In [22]: s = car.find(' ')
In [23]: car_1 = car[:s]
In [24]: car_2 = car[s+1:]
In [25]: s_2 = car_2.find(' ')
In [26]: car_3 = car_2[:s_2]
In [27]: car_name = car_2+' '+car_3
In [28]: car_name = car_1+' '+car_3
In [29]: car_name
Out[29]: 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class'
```

Comment: You need to give us the rules for when a split should happen.

Comment: Try `" ".join(car,split(" ", 2)[:2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple list comprehension would work

```
car_list=[
'Mercedes-Benz C-Class C180 CGI',
'BMW 3 Series 318i (New 5-yr COE)',
'Kia Cerato Forte 1.6M EX (COE till 03/2024)']

[' '.join(car.split(" ",2)[:2]) for car in car_list]
```

Output:

```
['Mercedes-Benz C-Class', 'BMW 3', 'Kia Cerato']
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the first two parts of a string that has spaces separating the parts, use `.split()` and `.join()`:

```
>>> s = "This sentence is a sample sentence."
>>> " ".join(s.split()[:2])
"This sentence"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split values on the basis of space and then join the first two indexes separated by space to get your desired output

```
>>> car = "Kia Cerato Forte 1.6M EX (COE till 03/2024)"
>>> newName = car.split(' ')
>>> ' '.join(newName[:2])
'Kia Cerato'
>>> car = "Mercedes-Benz C-Class C180 CGI"
>>> newName = car.split(' ')
>>> ' '.join(newName[:2])
'Mercedes-Benz C-Class'
>>>
```

Hope this helps.